# What are fantasy particles in RBMs

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, restricted-boltzmann-machine

In Restricted Boltzman Machines, when collecting the statistics I sometimes heard of fantasy particles being used.

What are these? How are they useful?

Answer (score 3):

Fantasy particles were first introduced by Tielman, using a technique for training RBMs called persistent contrast divergence. See:

[Training restricted Boltzmann machines using approximations to the likelihood gradient- Tieleman](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi8ir2Zg7TUAhWj5IMKHQOfAWAQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ficml2008.cs.helsinki.fi%2Fpapers%2F638.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH8p5GawsFCRlZ5esmCc6z0AKJQvQ&sig2=8lXEYiS-0u3qCV8VemUtrA).

and

[Using Fast Weights to Improve Persistent Contrastive Divergence -Tieleman, et. al.](http://people.ee.duke.edu/~lcarin/FastGibbsMixing.pdf)

From, [A Practical Guide for training Restricted Boltzmann Machines -- Hinton](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0ahUKEwj_kbbug7TUAhVk0oMKHcc7BFQQFghUMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.trade2win.com%2Fboards%2Fattachments%2Fmetatrader%2F96700d1290910624-3rd-generation-nn-deep-learning-deep-belief-nets-restricted-boltzmann-machines-practical-guide-training-rbm.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH2ILweyq_bw-YuTvrLWPkmww76ZQ&sig2=xQv878Wsl_6qHQzW-VVupw):

> A more radical departure from CD1 is called “persistent contrastive divergence” (Tieleman, 2008). Instead of initializing each alternating Gibbs Markov chain at a datavector, which is the essence of CD learning, we keep track of the states of a number of persistent chains or “fantasy particles”. Each persisitent chain has its hidden and visible states updated one (or a few) times after each weight update. The learning signal is then the difference between the pairwise statistics measured on a mini- batch of data and the pairwise statistics measured on the persistent chains. Typically the number of persistent chains is the same as the size of a mini-batch, but there is no good reason for this. The persistent chains mix surprisingly fast because the weight-updates repel each chain from its current state by raising the energy of that state (Tieleman and Hinton, 2009).

See also https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/csc2535/notes/lec4new.pdf

Comment: Sorry, what is a `Gibbs Markov chain` ?

Comment: @octavian: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling

Comment: Do you know of any simple numerical example of RBMs with Fantasy particles? Your explanation is great but a bit too abstract for me to understand.